# Set literal object to a component's Input property as a known object class

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component with an `@Input` property of type `Foo`:

```ts
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() Options: Foo;
  ...
}
```

And in the `ParentComponent.html` literal class pass to it as input value:

```html
<My [Options]="{prop1:true, prop2:false, prop3:1, ... }"></My>
```

Then type of `Options` is not `Foo` anymore. It changes to anonymous object and therefore methods of `Foo` are not accessible any longer.
One way to prevent this, is to create an instance of `Foo` in `ParentComponent .ts` and pass it as variable:

```ts
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ParentComponent {
  Options: new Foo(true, true, 1, ...);
  ...
}
```

And in the `ParentComponent.html` use:

```html
<My [Foo]="options"></My>
```

Another way would be to somehow cast anonymous object to the newly created `Foo` object:

```ts
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() set Options(value: Foo){
    //Somehow cast anonymous to Foo.
  }
  private options : Foo;
  ...
}
```

1. Is there any better or built-in way to do that?
2. If not, then how can I cast anonymous object to `Foo`?

Comment: can you add your scenario to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) ?

Comment: What do you mean *"it changes to anonymous object"*? It doesn't change at all, *you created that object* without the methods. You can't `new` something up in a [template expression](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions), so if you need it to be an instance of the class the second way you show above, creating it in the parent component class, is the correct way (except it should be `options = new Foo(...);`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you need to create an instance of your class `Foo` with `new` if you want to use the class methods using one of the two ways you described. If you want to pass in the plain object as your `@Input`, the input cannot be of (class-)type `Foo` because it is not an instance of that class. Within the class, you need to call `new Foo(fooInput)` and then e. g. assign the newly created instance to another member variable.

In my opinion, it would be better to have your data in a plain data object instead of a class: Define `Foo` as an `interface` instead of a `class` for type safety. Then, put the methods from the `class` into a `FooService`, which manipulates `Foo` objects. With this, you don't have to bother with class instantiation.

#### Example

```
class User {
  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {}

  getFullName(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  } 
}
```

becomes:

```
interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class UserService {
  getFullName(user: User): string {
    return `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: a simple snippet for `interface` solution would be nice.

Comment: I've added a simple example. Did this help you?

Comment: Yes it did. `UserService` works like a wrapper over `User` interface. Tanks.